# In cucumber jvm shared driver implementation Chrome driver does not reuse browser instance

Tags: cucumber-jvm

Has anyone one encountered the below problem before?

I am using the shared driver implementation OF cucumber jvm from https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/blob/master/examples/java-webbit-websockets-selenium/src/test/java/cucumber/examples/java/websockets/SharedDriver.java

However, Aslak Hellesøy has used firefox in its implementation. The problem is when I run the test with firefox,all the scenarios run fine irrespective of the number of scenarios in a feature file, however if I change the browser to chrome,it can only run one scenario in the feature file. Once the first scenario finish executing, chrome hangs and does not reuse the open browser instance unlike firefox which reuses the open browser instance by executing the next scenario.

Comment: It is versioning issue..check system has updated version..may be

Comment: I am using the latest chrome driver 2.2  from seleniumhq https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/

Comment: did you update our selenium jars too ?

Answer (score 0):

Following jars needs to update at same time to fix this problem

1. Always update selenium jars when you update your drivers(Chrome,Firefox o IE)
2. Always update grid jars

If you do not update entire environment at same time you will see this problem.

Advice :

- Do not update selenium or other jars automatically using regular expression, It is always to check what are update content and you really need this.
- Run Test before and after update to make sure environment up and running.